# How to get the accurate altitude from device with respect to the ground using unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, indoor-positioning-system, altitude

Hi I am working on an Indoor application for IOS application.I am trying to get latitudes,longitudes and altitudes.When I test the device the starting altitude value comes around

3.67853-first floor(starting point)

3.665541-second floor

3.538336-Ground floor

From the above values it is hard to know which floor the user is.Is there a way to get the correct altitude.

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(Getdata());
}


IEnumerator Getdata()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        yield break;

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start();

    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        print("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        print("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        Locationinformation.text = "Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp;
        print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }

    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the correct altitude'? Why are the above posted alts wrong? Hard to guess without knowing your use case - maybe i did not got you?

Comment: @nilsK Hey In the second floor the value becomes less and while going to ground floor also the value decreases.With respect to ground.Somehow set ground to 0 and from there value increases

Comment: Double check your gps signal quality/accuracy. Are you sure, these are 'good' positions? Also check if your altitude values are [MSL or AGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude). Seems you want AGL, but i don't know, if you can force your device to return AGL via configuration.

Comment: Yes but for indoor GPS values are not accurate right.For unity is there any was to get the AGL?Without that we cannot know which level the user is currently in.

Comment: Yes, accuracy indoor is a problem. I am not into unity and i believe this has more to do with your device / gps-driver then a framework or programming language - but this is guessing, not knowing! Coming from a company that develops telematik software i have some experience with gps, thats why i could say something to your problem - i dont have a solution for you, sorry. Just wanted to share some thoughts :)